# Matching Multiple Patterns with regex and execution on condition fails

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string with matching patterns for groupings and Tilde where separating those with list items. But when I have no pattern for some groups then it leaves that group.

See My Code Here

```php
$steps = '
--First Step ~30 mins~
First step method content goes here.
--Second Step ~10 mins~
Second step method content goes here.
--Third Step
Third step method content goes here.
';

$steps_list = explode( PHP_EOL, trim( $steps ) );

echo '<ol class="steps">';
foreach( $steps_list as $key => $data ) {
    if ( preg_match('/^\s*\-{2}(.*)([^~]+)(~([^~]+)~)/', $data, $matches )  && ( strpos( $data, '~' ) !== false ) ) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<h4 class="step_title">' . $matches[1] . '</h4>';
    echo '<span class="duration">' . $matches[3] . '</span>';
    } 
    else{
    //replacing data with span tags around it
    echo $data = str_replace( $data, '<p class="decription">' . $data . '</p>', $data );
    echo '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ol>';
```

**Results:**

```
<ol class="steps">
    <li>
        <h4 class="step_title">First Step</h4><span class="duration">~30 mins~</span>
        <p class="decription">First step method content goes here.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4 class="step_title">Second Step</h4><span class="duration">~10 mins~</span>
        <p class="decription">Second step method content goes here.</p>
    </li>
    <p class="decription">--Third Step</p>
    </li>
    <p class="decription">Third step method content goes here.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

1) In the above result if you notice the third steps throws wrong list without starting tag of li as it doesn't takes the third step as a title.

2) In the 1st and 2nd title durations part the `tilde` symbol is not trimming/removed in code execution.

***What I want the result is.***

```
<ol class="steps">
    <li>
        <h4 class="step_title">First Step</h4><span class="duration">30 mins</span>
        <p class="decription">First step method content goes here.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4 class="step_title">Second Step</h4><span class="duration">10 mins</span>
        <p class="decription">Second step method content goes here.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4 class="step_title">Third Step</h4>
        <p class="decription">Third step method content goes here.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<h4 class="step_title">Third Step</h4>` in third `<li>` ?

Comment: @Rahul - Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go.

Since your *time part* is optional in third step I checked if matches are more than 2.

Since there is no `~` in third part `strpos()` will return false. Changed it to `OR ||` condition.

`if ( preg_match('/^\s*\--([^~]+)(~([^~]+)~)?/', $data, $matches )  && ( strpos( $data, '~' ) !== false ) )`

to

`if ( preg_match('/^\s*\--([^~]+)(~([^~]+)~)?/', $data, $matches )  || ( strpos( $data, '~' ) !== false ) )`

Whole code will be as follows.

```
<?php
$steps = '
--First Step ~30 mins~
First step method content goes here.
--Second Step ~10 mins~
Second step method content goes here.
--Third Step
Third step method content goes here.
';

$steps_list = explode( PHP_EOL, trim( $steps ) );

echo '<ol class="steps">';
foreach( $steps_list as $key => $data ) {

if ( preg_match('/^\s*\--([^~]+)(~([^~]+)~)?/', $data, $matches )  || ( strpos( $data, '~' ) !== false ) ) {
echo '<li>';
echo '<h4 class="step_title">' . $matches[1] . '</h4>';
    if(sizeof($matches)>2){
    echo '<span class="duration">' . $matches[3] . '</span>';
    }
} 
else{
//replacing data with span tags around it
echo $data = str_replace( $data, '<p class="decription">' . $data . '</p>', $data );
echo '</li>';
}
}
echo '</ol>';
?>
```

Try it on [PhpFiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/)

Comment: that works fine, but if you give space before second step. I am trimming while using explode function but still the trim doesn't work I think. Can we trim the `$data` inside the foreach loop like `$data = trim($data);`